# Within An Array how can i stored IndexValue And Name

Tags: javascript, angular

Here I Have Simpleloop As

```
 handleFileInput(files: FileList,indexvalue:number) {
   Fileprop:File[]=[];
   FileIndex:number[]=[];
   
   for(var i=0;i<=files.length - 1;i++){
     this.Fileprop.push(files[i]);
     this.FileIndex.push(indexvalue);
   }
 }
```

Here how can I store Both Index And File in a single Object
Like

```
[
 {
   Index:0,
   File:'Something.jpg'
 },
 {
  Index:1,
  File:'Something1.jpg'
 }
]
```

Please Help me How can I stored in Array in the above format.
So that if any duplicate Index enter i can update the value
Thank you

Comment: Just store them as objects

Comment: @Andreas  could u please help me how can I overcome.. Actually I'm a junior programer

Comment: That should be part of almost any JS tutorial -> [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
data: Array<{Index: number; File: File}>

for(var i=0;i<=files.length - 1;i++){
  this.data.push({ Index: i, File: files[i] });
 }

console.log(this.data);
```

Comment: Getting Error at Index

Comment: can i get your Skype Id

Comment: @MdGosoddin you can upvote the answer, and why skypeid?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if you specifically want to track and update key-value entries.

```js
// Example adapted from MDN network
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set(0, 'Something.jpg');
map1.set(1, 'Something1.jpg');

console.log(map1.get(0)); // 'Something.jpg'
console.log(map1.get(1)); // 'Something1.jpg'
```